# Many timers on single page

Tags: javascript, timer

I have many countdown timers on the page. Timers countdown remaining time from current time to time in future.

I need to have current timer value seperate from html, because element on page may change (appear/disappear) cause filtering/sorting scripts.

My naive implementation just hangs out the browser:

```
var CountdownTimer = function(id, endTime) {    
    this.id = id;
    this.endTime = endTime;
    this.remainingSeconds = parseInt((this.endTime - CountdownTimer.startTime) / 1000);
};
CountdownTimer.prototype.start = function() {
    while (this.remainingSeconds > 0) {
        setTimeout('this.tick()', 1000);
    }
};

CountdownTimer.prototype.tick = function() {
    this.remainingSeconds--;
    console.log(this.id + ': ' + this.remainingSeconds);
};

CountdownTimer.startTime = new Date().getTime();

$(document).ready(function() {  
    var endTimes = Drupal.settings.snuper_filter.end_times,
        activeTimers = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < endTimes.length; i++) {
        activeTimers.push(new CountdownTimer(endTimes[i].nid, endTimes[i].endTime));
    }
    endTimes = Drupal.settings.snuper_filter.end_times = null;

    for (var i = 0; i < activeTimers.length; i ++) {
        activeTimers[i].start();        
    }

});
```

Could somebody give me some advice how to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're continuously setting timeouts in your `while` loop. Just set one timeout in `start` and set timeouts in the `tick` function (you need to set `self` to `this`):

```
CountdownTimer.prototype.start = function() {
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function() {self.tick()}, 1000);
};

CountdownTimer.prototype.tick = function() {
    this.remainingSeconds--;
    console.log(this.id + ': ' + this.remainingSeconds);
    if(this.remainingSeconds > 0) {
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function() {self.tick()}, 1000);
    }
};
```

Comment: +1 thorough / thoughtful answer, nice one. As an aside, could also consider using setInterval for this type of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand, what you need many timers, but next code made some optimization:

```
var CountdownTimer = function(id, endTime) {    
    this.id = id;
    this.endTime = endTime;
};

CountdownTimer.prototype.tickHandler=null;
CountdownTimer.prototype.start = function() {
  this.tickHandler=this.tick.bind(this);
  //or
  //var self=this;
  //this.tickHandler=function(){self.tick();};
  setTimeout(this.tickHandler, 1000);
};

CountdownTimer.prototype.tick = function() {
    var remainingSeconds=this.endTime-new Date().getTime();
    console.log(this.id + ': ' + remainingSeconds);
    if(remainingSeconds>0)setTimeout(this.tickHandler, 1000);
};
```

Comment: I should name my static variable startTime or pageLoadedTime instead of currTime. Probably it will make my code more readable. Corrected my code.